# Anchor a Cell to another one in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I create a spreadsheet(y) populated by a query from another spreadsheet (z)

The cells From A to D are populated by Query order by name.

Something like

```
A

Acme
Boo
Foo
```

from cell D to G I create formulas to generate a value for each cell.

something like

```
A         D

Acme      Myformula1
Boo       Myformula2
Foo       Myformula3
```

When add a value to main spreadsheet (z), the spreadsheet(y) with a query update its cells. For instance, I add AABB as value, the spreadsheet(z) will be:

```
A         D

AABB      Myformula1
Acme      Myformula2
Boo       Myformula3
Foo
```

It's wrong because Myformula1 is for Acme, myFormula2 is for Boo and so on.

is it possible to anchor myFormula1 to Acme?

Thanks

Comment: How many entries do you approximately have in column A? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: `=IF(A2="Acme",MyFormula1,IF(A2="Boo",",MyFormula2,IF(A2="Foo",",MyFormula3,"")))` .. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write your formula on spreadsheet (z) and use VLOOKUP from spreadsheet (y)